# Is there a Bing Maps API description how Bing transforms GeoJSON properties?

Tags: documentation, geojson, bing-maps

The title property of a GeoJSON file is automatically added as a label to the corresponding pushpin in Bing Maps v8, as you can see in the following screenshot of [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712812.aspx):

[image]

```
"title":"M 3.0 - 114km NNE of Punta Cana, Dominican Republic"
```

Is this behavior documented anywhere? Because I wonder if there are other special behaviors of property fields. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All properties of GeoJSON objects are added to the metadata property of the resulting Bing Maps shape. For example `pushpin.metadata = { /*GeoJSON info */}`

The callback for the GeoJSON module returns an array of shapes, so you would need to loop through each one to access each shapes individual metadata if you wanted it.

In addition to capturing this information some of it is also used to customize the shape. Basically, most shape options (pushpin, polyline, polygon) are supported. This is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712806.aspx Here is an example GeoJSON object that renders a pushpin red with a label of "New York":

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [-74.006393, 40.714172]
          },
          "properties": {
              "color": "red",
              "title": "New York"
          }
      }
    ]
}
```